# Using mutator and accesor methods in Java and creating objects to calculate the average of numbers

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, accessor, mutators

My assignment is to create a class to count, sum, and average a series of numbers. The specifications for the class AverageCalculator are:

instance variable of type int for the running sum that have been given to the AverageCalculator
instance variable of type int for the count of numbers that have been given to the AverageCalculator
no argument constructor: *AverageCalculator()*
a mutator method to add a number to the AverageCalculator: *void add(int newNum)*
an accessor method to return the sum of all the numbers added to the AverageCalculator: *int getSum()*
an accessor method to return the count, or number, of numbers added to the AverageCalculator: *int getCount()*
an accessor method to return the average of all numbers added to the AverageCalculator - note that the instance variables are int, and the return type is double, if no numbers have been added to the object, return 0: *double getAverage()*

Write a class, AverageCalculatorMain that contains a main method and does the following:

- create a AverageCalculator object, add one number ot the AverageCalculator, print sum, count, and average
- create another AverageCalculator object. Add three numbers, print sum, count, and average

This is what I have so far:

```
public class AverageCalculator {
    private int sum;
    private int count;
    
    public AverageCalculator() {
        sum = 0;
        count = 0;
    }
    public void add(int newNum) {
        this.sum = this.sum + newNum;
        count++;
    }
    
    int getSum() {
        return sum;
    }
    
    int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    
    double getAverage() {
        return sum / count;
    }
    
}
```

This is what I have for the main method:

```
public class AverageCalculatorMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        AverageCalculator average = new AverageCalculator(90);
        
        System.out.println("The sum is " + average.getSum() + "\nThe count is " + average.getCount() + "\nThe average is " + average.getAverage());
        

    }

}
```

However, when I try to create the new object (AverageCalculator average = new AverageCalculator(90);), there is an error saying it is undefined. How can I create this object and pass its value(s) successfully?

Comment: The error means you need to define a constructor accepting `int` parameter.  Or you can use default constructor.  Aside comment - you may get inaccurate calculation of the average value because you use integer division (e.g. 5/3 -> 1).

Comment: How can I produce a double by dividing integers?

Comment: Ignore the suggestions to add another constructor, that's not required for this assignment. Just remove the argument and instead call `add` on the object like this: `average.add(90)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to create an object using `parametrised constructor`

```
 AverageCalculator average = new AverageCalculator(90);
```

But you don't have `parametrised constructor` in your `AverageCalculator` class.

So change it to

```
 AverageCalculator average = new AverageCalculator();
```

OR

create a parametrised constructor.

```
public AverageCalculator(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
```

Or as per your need, you can create with two parameters i.e `sum` and `count`

EDIT:

You can have `setter` method

```
public void setCount(int sum) {
  this.sum = sum;
}
```

And after object creation, you can call this method to set the value.

Comment: How do I put in the values of the numbers I want to add if I don't use a parametrised constructor?

Comment: Please check my edit If you don't want to use `parametrised constructor`

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. Why do I put in the sum to set count? What if I want to pass in a series of numbers and have the program calculate the sum, like I did in `public void add(int newNum)`?

Comment: You need to open a new question I feel so. Hope I solved your problem with related to `undefined`.  I just meant the `variable` name is sum. You have to use collections i.e `java.util.List` to pass series of numbers.

Comment: According to the task description he should have neither an argumented constructor nor a setter, just call `add` once on the first created object and 3 times one the second one.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I didn't go through the entire task description. I was providing him the options apart from the original error he ran into.

Answer (score -1):

Define two constructors in your class ,

the no arg constuctor
and the one arg constructor

```
public AverageCalculatorMain(){}
public AverageCalculatorMain(int x){
 sum = x;
}
```

If you intend to pass an unknown number of arguments at run time then you should use varargs constructor

```
public AverageCalculatorMain(int ...x){
     
    }
```

or better still pass a collection as an argument to your constructor